# Multiple classappend and spacing

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this classappend on a  element

```
th:classappend="${(results.manualOverrideClash ? 'zv27' : '') + (results.skipSlp ? 'skipSlp' : '')}">
```

This works if either is true on its own, but if both are true then I end up with html

```
<tr class="zv27skipSlp"
```

which is an invalid class name. I want to apply both  classes, so how can I force a space so that the resulting html reads

```
<tr class="zv27 skipSlp"
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, actually it does. I had seen that Q & A before, but as Chris Haas points out below, I hadn't noticed the extra space in the second ternary

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

```
th:classappend="${(results.manualOverrideClash ? 'zv27' : '') + (results.skipSlp ? ' skipSlp' : '')}">
```

Comment: It might help to specifically point out that you are manually adding an extra space to `skipSlp` in the second ternary because it is otherwise very hard to tell what the change was.